# Не работает UserManager в asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

У меня проблема. Вот код моего метода входа, и каждый раз он возвращает false.

```
        public async Task<Object> Login(UserLoginForm user)
    {
        if (user.nick.Replace(" ", "") != "")
        {
            if (user.password.Replace(" ", "") != "")
            {
                Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult res = await _sign.PasswordSignInAsync(user.nick, user.password, false, false);
                return  _sign.IsSignedIn(_sign.Context.User);
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("log", "p");
            }
        }
        else
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("log", "e");

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));

    }
```

Вот код метода регистрации

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Registration(UserRegisForm user)
    {
        if (user.name.Replace(" ", "") != "")
        {
            if (user.email.Replace(" ", "") != "" && user.email.Length > 5)
            {
                if(user.nik.Replace(" ", "") != "" && user.nik.Length > 4)
                {
                    User usern = new User(user.name, user.second, 0, 0, 0, UserType.Standart) { Email = user.email, UserName = user.nik};
                    IdentityResult res =  await _users.CreateAsync(usern, user.password);
                    if (res.Succeeded)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Session.SetString("reg", "s");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HttpContext.Session.SetString("reg", res.Errors.First().Description);
                    }
                }
                else
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("reg", "n");
            }
            else
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("reg", "e");
        }
        else
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("reg", "na");

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Registration));
    }
```

Мне не понятно, почему он возвращает false, и как получить данные пользователя после входа. Обьясните пожалуйста

Comment: `user.nick.Replace(" ", "") != ""` странная медленная конструкция, замените на `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.nick)`

Comment: @aepot, объясните, как исправить код входа, и почему он не работает?) на счёт этих конструкций я знаю, но эти моменты кидал по быстрому, что пришло первое в голову, то и написал)

Comment: К сожалению, я не спец по ASP.NET, могу только посоветовать поотлаживать код. Ставьте точки останова, смотрите значения переменных во время выполнения. И валидация данных в контроллере - странное занятие, вот почитайте https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/19.1.php